# gdb - load kernel module on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gdb, kernel

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
user@peterubuntu0:$ insmod mymodule
user@peterubuntu0:/sys/module/mymodule/sections$ cat .text .data .bss
0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000
```

So how do I tell gdb where is my module loaded on target machine when I debug remotely? Do I use just the offsets (so 0x64 or 64 decimal for .text then?) in add-symbol-file command?

```
user@peterubuntu0:~$ objdump mymodule.ko --section-headers

mymodule.ko:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .text         0000b345  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000064  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
 12 .data         000001e4  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00012620  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
 15 .bss          00000014  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00012a80  2**3
                  ALLOC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat .text .data .bss` returns addresses of data sections only when executed as **root** (makes sense to me), otherwise returns 0x0000000000000000:

```
user@peterubuntu0:~$ su
user@peterubuntu0:~$ 
root@peterubuntu0:~$ cat .text .data .bss
root@peterubuntu0:~$ 0xffffffffa0518000
root@peterubuntu0:~$ 0xffffffffa073b000
root@peterubuntu0:~$ 0xffffffffa089b460
```